# Laptop at security checkpoints

Tags: transit, luggage

I am considering taking my laptop with me to a 3 weeks vacation to the US, I have a few questions regarding taking it through security.

1. Can I leave it in its sleeve?
2. Do I need to power it on, in order to prove it works?
3. Anything else I should know ?

Answer (score 2):

1. Normally, yes.
2. Normally, no.
3. I don't think so.

I am crossing US security checkpoints about 50 times a year, often with two laptops, and never got a question.

However, you should to be prepared to confirm ownership (by saying 'yes this is my laptop, not with paperwork), and start the booting if asked.

In Germany, when boarding flights to the US, they are more picky, and sometimes do explosives testing (they are wiping it with a probe and analyze the dust on it).

Nowadays, you probably stick out more if you travel *without* a laptop...

Edit: you are not allowed to have illegal content on it, like child pornography, Nazi propaganda, etc. Not that they'd ever check.

Comment: *Nowadays, you probably stick out more if you travel without a laptop...* Not sure about that, all of my travel in the past 6 years has been without a computer and no one really cares

Comment: @blackbird57: That's obviously not a general statement. However, it is probably true for *some* flights in *some* places at *some* times of day.

Comment: There is nothing illegal about Nazi propaganda in the United States!

Answer (score 2):

1. If it's iPad sized or smaller, you don't have take it out of your carry-on.  Larger devices must be separated, either in their own bin or a clam-shell type case.
2. No.
3. No.

Comment: What are clam-shell type cases?

Comment: Bing or Google things like "Checkpoint Friendly" or "TSA Approved" Laptop Case, you find many examples.